# Intermapper SNMP trap probe

Tags: cisco, snmp

What I have got set up are my Cisco switches send SNMP traps to my intermapper server. I did that so I could see who is logging in or trying to log in. That part is working. What I need to do is create a probe, then I can set up notifications and so on.

The SNMP trap looks like this

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.9.41.2 (1) { "SEC_LOGIN", "5", "LOGIN_FAILED", "Login failed [user: admin] [Source: 10.1.1.45] [localport: 22] [Reason: Login Authentication Failed] at 22:39:45 MDT Tue Jul 16 2013", "902084201" }
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the availability to notify me when someone logs into the switches. Since I am the only one who logs into them it would be nice to see if someone try to log in or actually logs in.

Comment: what kind of probe ae you looking for, an snmp trap receiver?

Comment: Yeah I think so, what I am trying to accomplish is the availability to notify me when someone logs into the switches. Since I am the only one who logs into them it would be nice to see if someone try to log in or actually logs in.

Comment: Hi mate,

Here is my suggestion:
 - use "login on-success log / login on-failure log" commands
 - then use EEM as for any of these two commands notify you in the syslog, it will send an email (automatically).

This is what I do on my critical equipments.

If you are interested I will post the EEM script.

Comment: @laf So the switch sends the email? That would be great if you posted the script.

Comment: Hi mate,

Unfortunately EEM is not supported on regular switches (2960, 35xx, 37xx). It's supported on 6500 platform, but that's pretty much all...

Comment: @Iaf I don't know where you got the idea that EEM isn't available on 3750's or is limited to 6500's.  See this link under Table 2, there are many supported platforms: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6555/ps6815/datasheet_c78-692254.html

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

If all you need is login notification and if you don't care about SNMP vs Syslog, you can use IOS built-in syslog for authentication failures and success.  It also can block IP addresses with failed logins.

```
login block-for 300 attempts 5 within 60
login on-failure log
login on-success log
```

This is the message for success

```
Jul 18 06:55:26.408: %SEC_LOGIN-5-LOGIN_SUCCESS: Login Success [user: cisco]
 [Source: 10.10.1.5] [localport: 23] at 06:55:26 UTC Thu Jul 18 2013
```

This is the message for a telnet failure

```
Jul 18 06:56:16.963: %SEC_LOGIN-4-LOGIN_FAILED: Login failed [user: ] 
 [Source: 10.10.1.5] [localport: 23] [Reason: Login Authentication Failed] at 06:56:16 UTC 
 Thu Jul 18 2013
```